# In Magento 2.4.1 How to Add custom fields to dashboard diagram totals and remove Tax, Shipping?

Tags: magento2, module, magento2.4.1, dashboard

I want to Remove Tax and Shipping and replace them with Quantity, Subtotal, Extra Fee, Total, etc[image]